# How can I change the icon size on lubuntu's desktop?

Tags: icons, lubuntu, customization, pcmanfm

I want to change the icons on the lubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lubuntu uses the ***LXDE Desktop Environment*** which in turns makes use of ***PCManFM*** to manage the desktop. Therefore in order to change the size of the desktop icons you need to access PCManFM Preferences and set the desired icon size.

Open PCManFM and Go to *Menu* → *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Display tab*

Enjoy!

Comment: I do not know what happened to me, the response was very good, as well as obvious lol! thank you very much, I have to wait like 20 hours to give you the points ..

Comment: No problem ;) It's not that obvious in Lubuntu so don't be to hard on yourself.